# Spring boot external properties not working

Tags: spring-boot

[image]

My project structure looks like as attached file. Even though I have profile specific properties, I would like to run my app with external properties file i.e., outside of jar file.

I tried with following command:

```
java -jar test_service.jar --spring.config.location=file:///C:/external_props/test.properties
```

But its taking application-default.properties file.

from log file:

```
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

Why it is not taking external properties file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring will automatically look for some property file in a specific location.

From where you execute the jar file, Spring will look in that directory for a property file called application.properties

An other way is to put a config directory in the directory you execute the jar from and put the application properties in there.

There is one more option and that is the `-Dspring.profiles.active={profiles}` parameter.

Spring will then look in the directory or config directory to application-{profile}.properties

Reference:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Also i think you use the
`--spring.config.location=file:///C:/external_props/test.properties`
is not used correctly for a windows based file path.
Windows uses the \ instead of the /.

Comment: Thanks. Its working only with: java -jar service.jar --spring.profiles.active=external --spring.config.location=file:///C:/external_props/application-external.properties

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `--spring.config.location` command line argument SpringBoot won't consider `application-*.properties` files in src/main/resources directory. The filename you mentioned for `--spring.config.location` is taken as base filename, in your case `test`. So, it will only load `test.properties` file from that path you provided as `default` profile.

If you want to enable certain profile, say `prod`, you need to create file `C:/external_props/application-prod.properties` and enable `prod` profile using `--spring.profiles.active=prod`.

Comment: @k-siva-prasad-reddy, No, even though I mentioned --spring.config.location=file:///C:/external_props/test.properties, its taking application-default.properties but not test.properties.

Comment: Are you saying that looking at logs? Do you have same properties in both application-default.properties and test.propties with different values and still it is loading values from application-default.properties?

Comment: @k-siva-prasad-reddy, I got it. If I remove application-default.properties then test.properties is taking. As per my understanding, if the profile not mentioned while running the application then it will look for application-default.properties. If that file is not there, then only it will take the file mentioned in "spring.config.location"